# How to eager load objects with a custom join in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

#### Background

Normal rails eager-loading of collections works like this:

```
Person.find(:all, :include=>:companies)
```

This generates some sql which does

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON people.company_id = companies.id
```

#### Question

However, I need a custom join (this could also arise if I was using `find_by_sql`) so I can't use the vanilla `:include => :companies`

The custom join/sql will get me all the data I need, but how can I tell activerecord that it belongs to the associated `Company` objects rather than just being a pile of extra rows?

#### Update

I need to put additional conditions in the join. Something like this:

```
SELECT blah blah blah
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON people.company_id = companies.id AND people.magical_flag IS NULL 
<Several other joins>
WHERE blahblahblah
```

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. Out of the box it's essentially impossible to impose dynamic conditions on the JOIN as opposed to the WHERE. Plugins/monkey patches appear to be the only reasonable solution at this stage.

Comment: Do you have any references to any plugins/patches that accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

Can you not add the join conditions using ActiveRecord?

For example, I have a quite complex query using several dependent records and it works fine by combining conditions and include directives

```
Contractors.find(
  :all, 
  :include => {:council_areas => :suburbs},
  :conditions => ["suburbs.postcode = ?", customer.postcode]                 
)
```

Assuming that:

1. Contractors have_many CouncilAreas
2. CouncilAreas have_many Suburbs

This join returns the Contractors in the suburb identified by **customer.postcode**.

The generated query looks like:

```
SELECT contractors.*, council_areas.*, suburbs.*
FROM `contractors` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `contractors_council_areas` ON `contractors_council_areas`.contractor_id = `contractors`.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `council_areas` ON `council_areas`.id = `contractors_council_areas`.council_area_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `council_areas_suburbs` ON `council_areas_suburbs`.council_area_id = `council_areas`.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `suburbs` ON `suburbs`.id = `council_areas_suburbs`.suburb_id WHERE (suburbs.postcode = '5000')
```

(Note: I edited the column list for brevity).

Comment: I don't think it works in modern Rails anymore: `Couldn't find Contractor with 'id'=all (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like the following to get the appropriate left outer join syntactical magic.

```
Person.reflect_on_association(:companies).options[:conditions] = 'people.magical_flag IS NULL'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's what you want (I'm not 100% sure I've understood your question and what you want to accomplish) but:

What about providing both `:joins` and `:includes`?

`Person.find(
  :all,
  :joins => 'LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON people.company_id = companies.id AND _pass_custom_conditions_here_',
  :includes => :companies
)`

Or AR3 way:

`Person.includes(:companies).joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON people.company_id = companies.id AND _pass_custom_conditions_here_')`

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate a bit more on exactly what you are trying to accomplish with this query?

Also take a look at at the :joins option for find. It allows you to specify how you want the tables joined. [link text](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001298/)

And beware when using :include, the behavior changes a bit in Rails 2.1 and may cause some problems when used in conjunction with a :conditions option that references an included table. [link text](http://pivots.pivotallabs.com/users/stevend/blog/articles/514-standup-09-23-2008-disabling-pre-rails-2-1-style-include/) and [link text](http://pivots.pivotallabs.com/users/stevend/blog/articles/515-standup-09-24-2008-why-does-my-jvm-crash-running-solr-/) are two articles from Pivotal that mention this gotcha.

Comment: I am using the :joins option with a string, but this (as far as I can tell anyway) defeats eager-loading, hence my question :-)